# Control backlight as a user (without xbacklight)

Tags: linux, xorg, wayland, backlight

I'm working on Gentoo and Intel *modesetting* driver for my video card. That's why `xbacklight` isn't working.

I can write inside */sys/class/backlight...* whith a root acount but that's not what I want to.
I saw somebody using `dbus-send` and HAL, but seems like HAL isn't on Gentoo (well there is `hal-flash`).
So I was wondering about a nice solution to control my backlight.

Oh wait, I just remembered `xrandr`. Is that the only option available for me? If there is a solution for both xorg and wayland that could be nice.

EDIT : It seems that `xrandr` donesn't modify */sys/class/backlight...* and I think this mean that it doesn't affect the battery charge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give yourself the permission to write to `/sys/class/backlight/*`, or add a sudo rule to modify the file. That's what I did when I had a computer with an i915 GPU.

For example, add something like the following code to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
chgrp -R backlighters /sys/class/backlight
chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/*/*
```

and add yourself to the `backlighters` group. If you want to give the permission to the user who's logged in on the console, that's harder, I think you'd have to hook into polkit and even then it's awkward because sysfs doesn't support ACL.

Comment: Well I guess I'll did that again then ^^ Thanks